# concept behind interchange of column vectors

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I came across a problem to find $A^{-1}$ if a matrix $A$ satisfies

$$A\begin{bmatrix}
3 &1  & 2\\ 
3 & 0 &2 \\ 
-1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 &  0&1 \\ 
 1&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I just used simple column vector Interchanging in right hand side matrix as follows

Interchange $C_1$ and $C_2$ and then Interchange $C_2$ and $C_3$ to get Identity matrix.

If we perform same operations to left hand side matrix we get a new matrix $$C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3 \\ 
 0& 2 &3 \\ 
1 &0  & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and magically that is $A^{-1}$.

Can i know what is the concept behind this?

But if i do same interchange to Rows, i am getting a different matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interchanging columns is equivalent to post-multiplying by a matrix, so you are reducing $AX = Y$ into $AXZ = YZ$ with $YZ=I$, so $A^{-1} = XZ$.

interchanging rows is pre-multiplying but that does not help here since you must do that to $A$, not to $X$...

Comment: I would be a little more precise "equivalent to post-multiplying by **the permutation** matrix **associated with the columns interchange**"

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is that when changing two row is related to [permutation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationMatrix.html).

For the operation of exchanging $C_1$ and $C_2$, the related matrix is:
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &0 \\ 
 1& 0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

For the operation of exchanging $C_2$ and $C_3$, the related matrix is:
$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &1 \\ 
0 &1  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A\begin{bmatrix}
3 &1  & 2\\ 
3 & 0 &2 \\ 
-1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}BC=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 &  0&1 \\ 
 1&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}BC \implies A \begin{bmatrix}
3 &1  & 2\\ 
3 & 0 &2 \\ 
-1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}BC= I $$, where I is identity matrix.

So the inverse of matrix $A$ is the $$\begin{bmatrix}
3 &1  & 2\\ 
3 & 0 &2 \\ 
-1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}BC$$
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3 \\ 
 0& 2 &3 \\ 
1 &0  & -1
\end{bmatrix}